# Error when validating the mimType of file in cakePHP

Tags: validation, mime-types, cakephp-3.0

i want to check the mimeType of an image uploaded, but i have this error :

**Cannot validate mimetype for a missing file**

and this is my code :

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->add('poster', [
            'myRule' => [
                'rule' => ['mimeType', ['image/png']],
                'message' => 'Just PNG files !'
            ]
        ]);


    return $validator;
}
```

I use CakePHP 3.x , thanks for help

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty specific... and if you [**look at the code**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.9/src/Validation/Validation.php#L906), it should be evident that the file to check seems to be missing or inaccessible. So, you should debug that, and then come up with some more details so that the problem becomes comprehensible/reproducable.

Comment: i don't think the file is missing, cause if i don't validate the data the file is uploaded to server, but when i validate the mimeType it run this error , if i debug the requested data , the file (poster) isn't missing ? so whats the issue ?

Comment: The actual uploaded file may not be missing, but whatever is being checked seems to, so again, you need to debug this, check what exactly is finally being validated in `Validation::mimeType()` and how it makes it there.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion , finally i do a custom validation to check the mimeType, i checked the mimeType function in the cake core validation class , the file_exists func to check the existence of file stop the cycle, some people suggest me that file_exists fail sometime if the file is to big in size , or the file name contain some special chars that fail when testing existence of file, this is so weird... :)